# IOS Google+ share presents empty prefillText

Tags: ios, google-plus, sharing

I've included the Google+ SDK inside my app to share to Google+ but whenever I try to share something the pre filled text results blank like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/um0bf4p3ennl0tu/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2026%20Dec%202013%2022.43.14.png

This is my code and it's not working even in the sample app provided by Google (I changed the client id and the bundle id of the sample app and discovered that what worked with the original config, didn't work anymore with mine, even if the sharing started ok), so I guess there must be something with the Google+ client id I created...

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID=kGooglePlusClientID;
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder=[[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"THIS IS THE PREFILLED TEXT"];
[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.babisoft.com"]];
[shareBuilder open];
```

Is anyone else facing this kind of problems?

Thank you

Stefano

Comment: this happens to me too.. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, I gave up and avoided the Google+ integration alltogether... anyway I'll retry with the Gabox solution asap...

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have solved your problem yet, but I have the same problem a day ago and I found the solution:

I solved that by using native share, if the user doesn't have permission you can tell the app to ask to Google+ for permission. (if it is not native Google+ have a bug that don't present the pre fill text to share)

I use this library which do this for you, but you can read the code and customise it.

https://github.com/lysannschlegel/GooglePlusShareActivity

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I saw on google+ framework documentation that the old classic sharebuilder will be soon deprecated...

use the nativeShareBuilder like @Gabox said  and all will work fine!﻿